# changing three DB names in a connection string

Tags: powershell, connection-string, app-config

I need to edit a script to change three connection strings in an app config file.  I have created a variable for the connection string giving server, dummy DB name, username and password.

So, the variable is `Server=serverName;Database=dummyDbName;User ID=userName;Password=securePassword`.

This is working well and config file is being updated accordingly.  The next stage is to iterate through the connection strings again and replacing dummyDbName with the connection string name, so if:

```xml
<add name="correctDbName" connectionString="Server=serverName;Database=dummyDbName;User ID=userName;Password=securePassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I want to change `Database=dummyDbName` to `Database=correctDbName`.

Am I on the right track?

```bsh
$appConfigFile = (Join-Path $filelocation)
$appConfig = [xml](Get-Content $appConfigFile) 

$dbName = ($appConfig.configuration.connectionStrings.add | Where-Object {$_.name -eq "aspnetdb"})
$dbName = $dbname -replace "dummyDbName", "aspnetdb"
```

Comment: This [TechNet blog post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/03/21/use-powershell-to-replace-text-in-strings/) should give you some guidance on using `-replace`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you're on the right track. But since the name you want to replace is in a property of the `<add>` node you need to modify that property, not the node itself:

```
$node = $appConfig.configuration.connectionStrings.add |
        Where-Object {$_.name -eq "aspnetdb"}
$node.connectionString = $node.connectionString -replace 'dummyDbName', 'aspnetdb'
```

Save the modified XML back to the file afterwards.

```
$appConfig.Save($appConfigFile)
```